# Accepting data-type of input dynamically

Tags: c++, c, generics

Hii ,

I was writing a generic function for sorting when i came across this idea . Usually we give the data and call the function sort which is written in a generic manner. I was wondering if we could accept the data-type of the input dynamically at run-time using generics .

Like , if we want to sort some data and we do not know the type of input that is given before hand . So , we need to take the data-type of input dynamically and perform the sort .

Is it possible .. ???

Comment: In what language?  The answers for C, C++, and Java may well be very different.

Comment: not sure if I understand the question, but isn't that what Java Array.sort(Object[], comparator) does?

Comment: I want to know if it can be done in C/C++ .. Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if only [somebody](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) had though of [that](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html) before...

Sort algorithms in libraries are generally pretty generic. You just need to tell them how to compare your objects.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if we could accept the data-type of the input dynamically at run-time using generics...
>
> ....we want to sort some data and we do not know the type of input that is given before hand...

No, you can't do that with C++ templates (I assumed you meant templates when you said generics).

C++ templates are a language feature that allows for types in code to be unspecified until the code that uses them is compiled. That is, C++ templates are a **compile-time** feature.

If all the types involved are known by the time the code is compiled, then you can use C++ templates. In your sorting example, if you know the exact types of the data to be sorted, then something like [the `std::sort()` function](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html) can be used.

If you can't determine the exact types of objects until runtime (which is apparently the situation you're describing), then polymorphism via `virtual` functions should be used. Using your sorting example, you may have a base class like this:

```
class SortableInput
{
public:
    virtual bool IsLessThan(SortableInput& rhs) = 0;
};
```

Then your different types can derive from it:

```
class SortableItemA : public SortableInput
{
public:
    virtual bool IsLessThan(SortableInput& rhs) { /* */ }
};

class SortableItemB : public SortableInput
{
public:
    virtual bool IsLessThan(SortableInput& rhs) { /* */ }
};

// ...
```

Then your sort function would only have to know about `SortableInput`. Of course, this only really makes sense if a `SortableItemA` can actually be compared against a `SortableItemB`.